# How to back our previous Activity after pressing cancel button in email?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I Have send emails from my Android application successfully,but I click on cancel(back button on gmail)button then my application goes into background,so 
How can I comeback from gmail application to my application when I pressed the cancel button in gmail application.

below my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:abc@gmail.com")); intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your Subject"); intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The message"); try { context.startActivity(intent); } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) { Toast.makeText(context, "Mail account not configured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

---

Comment: When you press the back button (the one at the bottom of the screen) you should end up back in your app. When you press the arrow in the upper left corner of the Gmail screen you'll end up in the message list. That's the intended behavior because this button is for in-app navigation, not a "back" button.

Answer (score 0):

You need change

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

to

```
context.startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

and add onActivityresult() to your Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
}
```

Comment: thanks for comment ,but issue not solved using above code.